# How to plot equation between -1 to 1 or how to normalize a equation for plotting between -1 to 1

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, eigenvalues

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Clear[b]
L = 4;
z1 = L/3;
z2 = (2*L)/3;
Y = 2*10^11;
Iyy = 8.333*10^-6;
A = 0.1^2;
kb = (Y*Iyy)/L^3
W1 = A1*Sin[b*x] + B1*Cos[b*x] + C1*Sinh[b*x] + E1*Cosh[b*x];
W2 = A2*Sin[b*x] + B2*Cos[b*x] + C2*Sinh[b*x] + E2*Cosh[b*x];
W3 = A3*Sin[b*(x - z2)] + B3*Cos[b*(x - z2)] + C3*Sinh[b*(x - z2)] + 
   E3*Cosh[b*(x - z2)];
(*SS BC*)
bcd0 = W1 /. {x -> 0};
bcm0 = (D[W1, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> 0};
bcdl = W3 /. {x -> L};
bcml = D[W3, {x, 2}] /. {x -> L};
(*CC BC*)
(*bcd0=W1/.{x\[Rule]0};
bcm0=(D[W1,{x,1}])/.{x\[Rule]0};
bcdl=W3/.{x\[Rule]L};
bcml=D[W3,{x,1}]/.{x\[Rule]L};*)
(*CANTILEVER BC*)
(*bcd0=W1/.{x\[Rule]0};
bcm0=(D[W1,{x,1}])/.{x\[Rule]0};
bcdl=(D[W3,{x,2}])/.{x\[Rule]L};
bcml=(D[W3,{x,3}])/.{x\[Rule]L};*)
(*FF BC*)
(*bcd0=(D[W1,{x,2}])/.{x\[Rule]0};
bcm0=(D[W1,{x,3}])/.{x\[Rule]0};
bcdl=(D[W3,{x,2}])/.{x\[Rule]L};
bcml=(D[W3,{x,3}])/.{x\[Rule]L};*)
(*Compatability condition for first spring*)
ccd1 = (W1 /. {x -> z1}) - (W2 /. {x -> z1})
ccs1 = ((D[W1, {x}]) /. {x -> z1}) - ((D[W2, {x}]) /. {x -> z1})
ccm1 = ((D[W1, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> z1}) - ((D[W2, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> z1})
ccsh1 = ((D[W1, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> z1}) - ((D[W2, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> 
      z1}) - K1*(W2 /. {x -> z1})
(*Compatability condition for second spring*)
ccd2 = (W2 /. {x -> z2}) - (W3 /. {x -> z2})
ccs2 = ((D[W2, {x}]) /. {x -> z2}) - ((D[W3, {x}]) /. {x -> z2})
ccm2 = ((D[W2, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> z2}) - ((D[W3, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> z2})
ccsh2 = ((D[W2, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> z2}) - ((D[W3, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> 
      z2}) - K2*(W3 /. {x -> z2})

(*Forming matrix*)
R = Normal@
   CoefficientArrays[{bcd0, bcm0, bcdl, bcml, ccd1, ccs1, ccm1, ccsh1,
       ccd2, ccs2, ccm2, ccsh2}, {A1, B1, C1, E1, A2, B2, C2, E2, A3, 
      B3, C3, E3}][[2]];
R1 = MatrixForm[R]
MatrixRank[R];
P = FullSimplify[Det[R]];

(* FOR FINDING THE FIRST MODE SHAPE M11*)
K1 = 10^12/L^3;
K2 = 0.01/L^3;
eq1 = P;
Plot[eq1, {b, 20, 40}];
S = NSolve[eq1 == 0 && 0 < b < 20];
vec = b /. S;
i = 1;
b = vec[[i]]
SS = R // MatrixForm;
NN = NullSpace[R];
NN1 = NullSpace[R] // MatrixForm
r = 1;
A1 = NN[[r, 1]];
B1 = NN[[r, 2]];
C1 = NN[[r, 3]];
E1 = NN[[r, 4]];
A2 = NN[[r, 5]];
B2 = NN[[r, 6]];
C2 = NN[[r, 7]];
E2 = NN[[r, 8]];
A3 = NN[[r, 9]];
B3 = NN[[r, 10]];
C3 = NN[[r, 11]];
E3 = NN[[r, 12]];
m11 = Piecewise[{{W1, x <= z1}, {W2, z1 <= x <= z2}, {W3, x >= z2}}];
Plot[m11, {x, 0, L}]
```

Now i have m11 , i have to plot the above equation between -1 to 1. It is essentially a eigen vector kind of  thing and i want to visualize in a normalized way, I tried using **normalize** but it didnt work.how to do this. I have tried by taking  inner product of the m11 and integrated over the domain. I found the normalized constant and later i divide the equation by this normalized constant , but still it didnt work.

Comment: I suppose the minimal aspect of a [minimal working code example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) escaped your notice.  There are two `Plot` commands, several lines of commented-out code, an unnecessary `NN1`, etc., yet the question in the title seems much simpler and clearer. The large amount might discourage others from answering or even reading your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. and i mentioned m11 as my equation of interest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the idea is to rescale the plot, I suppose a linear rescaling $(x,y) \mapsto (x, ay)$ is what is desired.

Example plot:

```
plot = Plot[x^3 - 3 Sin[x], {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Linear rescaling:

```
Show[
 plot /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, y/Max@Abs@Last@PlotRange@plot},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Affine rescaling $(\text{min},\text{max}) \mapsto (-1,1)$, in case that is desired:

```
Show[
 plot /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, Rescale[y, Last@PlotRange@plot, {-1, 1}]},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think this is what i was looking for . Thanks . but  is  it similar to normalize?

Comment: And what if i want  to do it for multiple plots  compare them in one single plot ? how to  carry this! I used Show command but didnt work

Comment: @vijay You'll need to get the overall plot range and then rescale; the easiest way is probably to combine the plots first, `plot = Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> All]`, then do the above.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer on how to normalize your function, but an answer on how to plot a function from $-1$ to $1$. I don't think that these two procedures are equivalent, but I am not sure if it holds for your purposes.

I am considering a simple example to illustrate and make it clear.

Suppose a function $f(x)$ given by

```
f[x_] := x^3 + x^2 - x^5
```

And now you want to plot the above in the interval $-1$ to $1$.

The command is

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

And the plot is the following

[image: The Plot]

I hope this helps.

Cheers!!!